# Unable to publish APK to Visual Studio App Center using Azure DevOps Release pipeline

Tags: azure, xamarin, azure-devops, hockeyapp, visual-studio-app-center

I created one release pipeline which is responsible of pushing APK file to App Center. However, when I try to deploy that task it is always failing with below error:

```
> <!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n<meta
> charset=\"utf-8\">\n<title>Error</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<pre>Cannot
> POST
> /v0.1/apps/https://appcenter.ms/users/username/apps/VSTSBuild/release_uploads</pre>\n</body>\n</html>\n
```

My Task Configurations:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just followed this [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/vsts-deploy) and I was able to create a release,

Please make sure the App slug and the Binary file path are correct/
Your app slug should be Username/AppName
and The binary file path should be 'app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release-unsigned.apk'

[image]